# Why Spring Batch reads metadata tables from MASTER and not from User defined Schema?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch, database-metadata

I have a spring boot batch application. In `application.properties`, I specify my data source details as follows

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://1*.2**.6*.25:14**
spring.datasource.database=MYDB_DEV
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
```

The problem is, when I run the batch job, all user defined tables are taken from the MYDB_DEV. But Metadata tables like BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION, BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT are taken from the MASTER schema even though I have created the same tables in MYDB_DEV. Why this happens? Is there any work around to make the application read Metadata tables from user defined schema?

I have debugged though the `jobLauncher.run(myjob, jobParameters)`, Could not find any lead from where it is taking master Schema

Answer (score 3):

Use below property in `application.properties` or `application.yml`

```
spring.batch.tablePrefix=MYDB_DEV.BATCH_
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! We have already tried this approach. Still not working. Spring boot version we are using is 1.2.5. Tried both spring.batch.tablePrefix and
spring.batch.table-prefix with schema names as well.